# Difference between ensembling models and using one model as a feature in the second model?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, boosting, feature-engineering, ensemble-learning

I have 2 models - one is a **generative model** (a model which assets the parameter of some distribution for each individual object needs to be predicted, and *does not learn from any data*), and the second is an **XGBoost** (which of course learns from training data).

I wonder what is the difference between -

- **Ensembling the 2 models** (i.e - run them both, and then combine their independent results)
- **Adding to the XGBoost** model a **feature**, which is the **result of the generative model**

What's the difference between the 2 options? When do I choose which one?

Comment: Choose the one that gives better held-out performance?

Comment: Why do you think the generative model does not learn from the data?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy There is not a clear answer to that, and I believe that corporating both of them will give a better result.

Comment: @JayaramIyer The generative model assets a distribution for each object that needs to be predicted, and from the found distribution - predicts a value. So no learning here.

Comment: How does the generative model assess a distribution without any data?

Comment: @jbowman it assess a distribution parameter (it is given that each data point comes from a normal distribution) for each individual data point. i.e not with training data.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question - *how*.  What do you mean by "assess"?

Comment: @jbowman I have my data object which contains few samples, each. from the samples, I find the mean and standard deviation.

Comment: Well, that's learning from data, specifically, estimating the means and standard deviations using the samples that each data object contains.

Comment: @jbowman Yes in that sense you are right. What I meant at first was that there isn't "training data". Any insight about the problem? :)